# Which is more better to use $(function(){}); or $(document).ready(); and why?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between using

```
$(function(){
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

Have tried both , both work well but what happens at runtime.

Comment: *better* is dependant on an individuals experiences thereby making this question primary opinionated. If you have a specific issue, by all means edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: They are same, Read official doc [document-ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: If I remember well, it's exactly the same. First is shorter.

Comment: You can also use ES6 syntax `$(() => { })`, still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The both do exactly the same thing, but the second form is not recommended in jQuery v3. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) in the documentation. From that second link:

> jQuery offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the DOM is ready. All of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $( handler )
> $( document ).ready( handler )
> $( "document" ).ready( handler )
> $( "img" ).ready( handler )
> $().ready( handler )
> ```
>
> As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other syntaxes still work but are deprecated.

Comment: Uh? How is `$("img").ready` equivalent to `$(document).ready`? What am I missing? Why `img`?

Comment: @JeremyThille: Because the contents of the jQuery object are **completely** ignored by `ready`; see the code starting with `jQuery.fn.ready =` [in the unminified file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js). Personally, I'd prefer the documentation didn't include that example (and that using `ready` on a set containing anything but `document` threw an exception), but...they didn't consult me. ;-)

Comment: Wow, I had no idea. So why bother writing `document` or anything else in the first place if this argument is completely ignored? Weird.

Comment: @JeremyThille I'm assuming people put the first parameter for code clarity.

Comment: @JeremyThille: Indeed, there are several weird things about the jQuery API. :-) The hyper-overloading of the `$()` function where it changes what it does markedly depending on both the type and (in the case of strings) content you pass it (sometimes doing DOM selection, other times HTML parsing, other times registering a DOM ready handler) is one of my least favorite things about the API. I would have **much** preferred `$(selector)`, `$.parse(htmlString)`, `$.domReady(callback);`, ... But again, curiously, they didn't consult me. ;-)

Comment: (There is a `$.parseHTML` though...)

Comment: Well there's still time to make a pull request for the next jQuery version :)

Comment: @JeremyThille: Oh, marked changes to the jQuery API are...effectively never going to happen. :-D I imagine something new will eventually supplant jQuery, it's ever the way of things. MVC frameworks, DOM improvements, and modern browser standardization are definitely reducing the need for it. I'd love for jQuery's set-orientation to make its way into some new DOM API. Closest so far is the recent addition of `forEach` to `HTMLCollection`...

Answer (score 0):

1.==>> $(document).ready(function(){
});
-This is to prevent any jQuery code from running before the document is finished loading.
-This also allows you to have your JavaScript code before the body of your document, in the head section.

2.==> $(function(){

});
-This is shorter method for the document ready event.

**Both methods are works but the document ready event is easier to understand when reading the code.**